# How to get the last element in each time frame in a resampled DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

So I've resample a bid and ask `.csv` file into an `ohlc` data set.

```
csv_file = pnd.read_csv("./data/APPL.csv", sep=',', header=True, names=['DateTime', 'Bid', 'Ask'],  index_col='DateTime', date_parser=parse, parse_dates={'DateTime'},)
```

add it to a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pnd.DataFrame(csv_file)
```

and resampled it, like:

```
ohlc_data = df.resample('15Min', how={'Bid':'ohlc'})
```

Now, I want to access last elements in each bar, or say `ohlc` data set?

for example, I want to access the last element that was resampled in this `ohlc` bar.

```
2016-03-13 00:00:00  1.11384  1.11757  1.11354  1.11651
```

this is one row in resampled `DataFrame`, how can I know the last element of the original data in that row?

Comment: it would be great if you can provide example of data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'last' item is the value from the `close` column for a particular date, you can use either `.iloc[]` for integer-based access, or `.loc[]` for queries based on time.

Some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'price': np.random.random(1000)}, index=pd.date_range(start=datetime.now(), freq='Min', periods=1000))

resampled = df.resample('15Min').ohlc() # new resample syntax in version 0.18
resampled.tail()
                        price                              
                         open      high       low     close
2016-05-15 03:15:00  0.459310  0.929793  0.054702  0.750257
2016-05-15 03:30:00  0.240577  0.946072  0.051050  0.387052
2016-05-15 03:45:00  0.827814  0.860241  0.083638  0.658283
2016-05-15 04:00:00  0.507453  0.982945  0.100041  0.705432
2016-05-15 04:15:00  0.970364  0.970364  0.102864  0.859491

resampled.iloc[-1, 3]

0.85949050966

resampled.loc['2016-05-15 04:15:00', ('price', 'close')]

0.85949050966
```